# Problem with variable assignment in python

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

I'm running the following code in python:

```
w= np.random.rand(3) 
w_old=np.zeros((3,))

while (np.linalg.norm(w - w_old)) / np.linalg.norm(w) > 1e-5:

    w_old=w

    print w
    print w_old

    w[0]-=eta*dE1i
    w[1]-=eta*dE2i
    w[2]-=eta*dE3i

    print w
    print w_old
```

The results for the prints are :

```
[ 0.22877423  0.59402658  0.16657174]

[ 0.22877423  0.59402658  0.16657174]
```

and

```
[ 0.21625852  0.5573612   0.123111  ]

[ 0.21625852  0.5573612   0.123111  ]
```

I'm wondering why the value of `w_old` has been changed? Shouldn't it be updated after going back to the beginning of the while loop? How can I fix this?

Comment: Every change to w also affects w_old. The equals assignment isn't doing what you think it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using

```
w_old = w
```

doesn't copy `w`, using `=` just tells python that you want another name for whatever is stored in `w`. So every in-place change to `w` will also change `w_old`. There is a really nice blog post about it in case you want more details [Ned Batchelder: "Facts and myths about Python names and values"](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

You can explicitly copy a numpy array, for example, using the [`copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html) method:

```
w_old = w.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear things up, variables are independent so:

```
a=5
b=a
```

will work just fine if you change either `a` or `b`. But lists and dictionaries cannot be copied the same way, so:

```
a=[1,2]
b=a
a[0]=100
print(b[0])
```

will give you 100 because now `a` and `b` are the same thing with two names. So as suggested before use

```
w_old = w.copy()
```

instead so `w_old` is a new list and not just another name for the old one.

Comment: Even they are just integers: assignment won't copy them. The difference is just that: There is no way you can change an integer in-place so you never "notice" that it's the same object (except when you use `is`).

Answer (score 0):

Just to conclude the answers above, according to [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
>   bindings between a target and an object.

So, the solution is

> For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is
>   sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the
>   other.

So using `copy()` we can rewrite the code as

```
import numpy as np

w= np.random.rand(3)
w_old=np.zeros((3,))

while (np.linalg.norm(w - w_old)) / np.linalg.norm(w) > 1e-5:

    w_old=w.copy()

    print(w)
    print(w_old)

    w[0]-=0.01
    w[1]-=0.01
    w[2]-=0.01

    print(w)
    print(w_old)
```

and get

```
[0.79666571 0.82305671 0.41167625]
[0.79666571 0.82305671 0.41167625]
```

and

```
[0.78666571 0.81305671 0.40167625]
[0.79666571 0.82305671 0.41167625]
```